# How to properly import into angular modules? Can't figure out which piece I'm missing.

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular-module

Is there a problem with calling out the PrimeNg references in multiple modules? Or should I have it in a shared module? Is there a best practice there?
It seems that I am failing to import "p-dataTable" from primeng but I do have it in the module where the component is declared.

The error I am getting referring to my html in validation.component.html:

```
errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dataTable'.
1. If 'p-dataTable' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dataTable' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the @NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<body>
    <h3>Validation tabs go here.</h3>
    <p-dataTable [ERROR ->][value]="validationsList" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedValidation" dataKey="id"
    "): ng:///app/validation/validation.component.html@7:17
```

I have validation.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedModule } from "../shared/shared.module";
import { ValidationComponent } from "./validation.component";
import { SampleIdsTableComponent } from "./sampleIdsTable.component";
import { AllTestsComponent } from "./allTests.component";
import { RunStatusComponent } from "./runStatus.component";
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NglModule } from 'ng-lightning/ng-lightning';
import {
SharedModule as Prime_SharedModule,
TabMenuModule, AccordionModule, MenuModule, MenubarModule,     SelectButtonModule,
CalendarModule, InputTextareaModule, DataTableModule, ChartModule, DataGridModule
} from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: '',
            component: ValidationComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                },
                {
                    path: 'samples',
                    component: SampleIdsTableComponent
                },
                {
                    path: 'allTests',
                    component: AllTestsComponent
                },
                {
                    path: 'runStatus',
                    component: RunStatusComponent
                }
            ]

        },
        Prime_SharedModule,
        TabMenuModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        NglModule.forRoot(),
        AccordionModule,
        DataTableModule,
        MenuModule,
        MenubarModule,
        SelectButtonModule,
        CalendarModule,
        ChartModule,
        InputTextareaModule,
        DataGridModule
    ])
],
declarations: [
    ValidationComponent,
    SampleIdsTableComponent,
    AllTestsComponent,
    RunStatusComponent
],
providers: [
]
})
export class ValidationModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Brackets! Count the brackets. I was adding all of my imports to the RouterModule.forChild([...]) instead of the imports array.